# Base URL in CP keeps defaulting to @web/

Tags: craft3

In the CP > Settings > Sites, setting the Base URL keeps defaulting to `@web/`

I have an environment variable `$DEFAULT_SITE_URL` set up in my [.env] file, and this is recognized (auto-fill suggests it and I can select it) by the CP, but when I save the settings and return to the page, the Base URL has reverted to `@web/`.

I've tried removing the @web alias I have in my .env file  `'@web' => getenv('DEFAULT_SITE_URL'),` but this only results in the CP warning *The @web alias is not recommended if it is determined automatically.*

It seems I may have some hard-set setting somewhere, but I would not know where.
An [old post from Brandon](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/3559#issuecomment-465297478) suggests checking the [config/project.yaml] file but I'm not finding any reference to the Base URL there or `$DEFAULT_SITE_URL`.

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to figure this out: in my .env file I had still defined `'siteUrl' => getenv('DEFAULT_SITE_URL'),`
Apparently having that alias named 'siteURL' locked the Base URL to keep defaulting to @web/. Deleting the alias resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Does this work?

general.php

```
 'aliases' => [
      '@defaultSiteUrl' => getenv('DEFAULT_SITE_URL'),
  ];
```

And in **CP > Settings > Site** set your Base url to:
`@defaultSiteUrl`

1. iirc using `@web` as your base url is not supported anymore
2. The value of `DEFAULT_SITE_URL` in your .env is set to an url right? something like `http://domain.test`?

Comment: Thanks for the help! Unfortunately your suggestion does the same as what I've tried earlier: whether I use and environment variable, an alias or a literal URL in the Base URL field, when I save the settings and return to the page, Craft has reverted the field's value back to '@web/' again. It seems as though there is some override in a config file or something, but I don't know where that would be.